JDA sends Embed correctly but shows "application did not respond"
I have been working on a Destiny 2 Raidbot on Discord. Here i came across a problem where i havent found a solution yet.
My Problem: Correct Embed but error Message,
the Embed is send right after you enter the /command.
My code so far:
event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(mb) // Mb is a simple created MessageEmbed
                .setActionRow(List.of(          // Here are normally some buttons as you see in the image above
                        
                )).queue(message -> {   // Here I want to extract the messageId from the freshly created message by the Discord bot
                    String messageId = message.getId();
                    postMap.put(messageId, new Post(event.getUser().getId(), raid.getPlayerCount()));   // messageId gets saved in a map for later use
                }
        );

As further Information that could cause the Problem: I have a SlashHandler that keeps the code
(hopefully) stuctured and readable (=.
public Listener(List<Slash> slashList) {
        slashList.forEach(v -> SLASHMAP.put(v.getName(), v));
    }
    @Override
    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
        SLASHMAP.get(event.getName()).onSlashCommandEvent(event, POSTMAP);
    }

I already tried:

using event.event.replyEmbeds() -> doesnt seem to have good way to extract the messageID
Tried with hook() and deferReply() -> maybe there is something more that needs a reply


If you use getHook(), you don't need a message id. You can use editOriginal and similar methods instead. Can you elaborate in your post why the messageId is relevant?

@Minn i want to use the messageId to assign the right array of players that join to the correct embed. Nevertheless, i think i figured it out. You need to have two replies for this kind of interaction ill write a comment to clerify.

All interaction reply messages include the interaction information on the message, that can be used to identify the message instead of the id. I recommend to make posts about your initial problem instead of issues with attempted solutions.

I have added a second event.reply(). This stopped the Interaction from failing/not responding.
event.reply("").queue();
event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(mb).queue(message -> {   // Here I want to extract the messageId from the freshly created message by the Discord bot
                String messageId = message.getId();

});

)
This is not an elegant solution but it seems to work for now.
